# Expo build online in stores without distribution

Tags: ios, build, expo

Problem:
If I run `expo build:ios` my code instantly goes live on the AppStore. Even if I don't upload the build to AppStore Connect. Seems like the javascript is loaded directly from the expo server. This behaviour is new to me. It wasn't like that before. I think it's working like that since I once tried `eas build`. What can I do to get rid of this?

Comment: if you use expo updates, your changes are uploaded to the default release channel

Comment: In my app.json I set the updates like this 
`"updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "enabled": false,
      "checkAutomatically": "ON_ERROR_RECOVERY"
    },`.
I even removed expo-updates from my dependencies. My app is still loading the JavaScript from the expo servers.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
My code/settings was/were fine.
I just needed to publish a version via AppStore and Play Store and now the apps aren‘t loading the JavaScript on app start.

Comment: It would be helpful to link to any documentation that supports your solution.